# Java generics - compiler error

Tags: java, generics

What's wrong with this method definition?

```
public static List<T extends MyObject> T find() {

}
```

Compiler says:

```
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete MethodDeclaration
```

Comment: Is your class generic ? if not you must delare the method like this: `public static <T> List<T extends MyObject> T find()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two return types there.

If you wanted to introduce a generic type `T` that would be

```
 public static <T extends MyObject>  List<T> find() {}
```

Answer (score 2):

The proper method declaration would be:

```
public static <T extends MyObject> List<T> find() { ... }
```

When creating (static) generic methods, the generic parameter(s) has to be defined before the return-type, because they may be used in the return-type.